# Can't center custom paint

Tags: flutter

So.., I created a battery icon and a network icon with custom paint, the battery icon seems to work well but I'm having problems with centering my network icon.

I'm guessing it's a size(scaling) issue.

Network Icon:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SignalBar extends CustomPainter {
  const SignalBar({this.signalStrength = 4});
  final int signalStrength;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var barBorder = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.black
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 1.5;
    var barWidth = size.width * 0.15;

// Signal bar borders
    for (var i = 0; i < signalStrength; i++) {
      canvas.drawRRect(
          RRect.fromRectAndRadius(
              Rect.fromLTWH(size.width * (i * 0.22), size.height * -(i * 0.05),
                  barWidth, size.height * ((i * 0.05) + 0.2)),
              const Radius.circular(8)),
          barBorder);
    }
    var barFill = Paint()
      ..color = (signalStrength <= 2)
          ? Colors.red
          : (signalStrength <= 3)
              ? Colors.orange
              : Colors.blue.shade600
      ..strokeWidth = 1;
// Signal bar fill
    for (var i = 0; i < signalStrength; i++) {
      canvas.drawRRect(
          RRect.fromRectAndRadius(
              Rect.fromLTWH(size.width * (i * 0.22), size.height * -(i * 0.05),
                  barWidth, size.height * ((i * 0.05) + 0.2)),
              const Radius.circular(8)),
          barFill);
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant SignalBar oldDelegate) {
    return true; //oldDelegate.signalStrength != signalStrength;
  }
}
```

Code for icons row:

```dart
Container(
              //margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30),
              width: 125,
              height: 42,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                  color: Colors.white12),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  AnimatedBatteryIcon(
                      duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
                      chargeValue: stringToInt(data?.batteryValue) ,
                      isCharging: data?.batteryCharging == "1" ? true : false),
            
                  Text(
                    "${data?.batteryValue}%",
                    style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                    child: CustomPaint(
                      painter: SignalBar(
                          signalStrength: stringToInt(data
                              ?.signalbar)), //BatteryIcon(chargeValue: BatteryChargeValue.half),
                      size: Size(15, 50),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
```

No matter how I change the `size` on the network icon, it just doesn't align.

Image:

[image: Pictorial representation]

From the code, you can see that my battery icon doesn't have an `Align` or those position widgets on it but it fits perfectly (I think).

**Edit:** The Align widget is just me testing out different situation (solution). Either way, it doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to align the network icon with the battery icon on the same baseline, you may need to remove the Align widget around the CustomPaint widget.

You can also use the crossAxisAlignment property of the Row widget to set different vertical alignments.

Comment: The Align widget is just me testing things out.

Answer (score 1):

This is the sizing issue of the custom paint.I modified your code as follows.

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool isVisible = false;

  void _changeVisibility() {
    setState(() {
      isVisible = !isVisible;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: Container(
        //margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30),
        width: 125,
        height: 42,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30)),
            color: Colors.grey),
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned(
              left: 5,
              top: 10,
              bottom: 10,
              child: Container(
                width: 25,
                height: 25,
                color: Colors.yellow,
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text(
                "10%",
                style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
            const Positioned(
              right: 0,
              top: 17,
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 22,
                height: 45,
                child: CustomPaint(
                  painter: SignalBar(
                      signalStrength:
                          3), //BatteryIcon(chargeValue: BatteryChargeValue.half),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )),
      // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}

class SignalBar extends CustomPainter {
  const SignalBar({this.signalStrength = 4});
  final int signalStrength;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var barBorder = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.black
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 1.5;
    var barWidth = size.width * 0.15;

// Signal bar borders
    for (var i = 0; i < signalStrength; i++) {
      canvas.drawRRect(
          RRect.fromRectAndRadius(
              Rect.fromLTWH(size.width * (i * 0.22), size.height * -(i * 0.05),
                  barWidth, size.height * ((i * 0.05) + 0.2)),
              const Radius.circular(8)),
          barBorder);
    }
    var barFill = Paint()
      ..color = (signalStrength <= 2)
          ? Colors.red
          : (signalStrength <= 3)
              ? Colors.orange
              : Colors.blue.shade600
      ..strokeWidth = 1;
// Signal bar fill
    for (var i = 0; i < signalStrength; i++) {
      canvas.drawRRect(
          RRect.fromRectAndRadius(
              Rect.fromLTWH(size.width * (i * 0.22), size.height * -(i * 0.05),
                  barWidth, size.height * ((i * 0.05) + 0.2)),
              const Radius.circular(8)),
          barFill);
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant SignalBar oldDelegate) {
    return true; //oldDelegate.signalStrength != signalStrength;
  }
}
```

and the result is

[image]

Comment: I only added the `Align` widget to test things. BTW the alignment doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not worried about the height. It's the position that's my problem. In my picture you would notice the signal bar is not placed at the centre but at the top.

Comment: You updated method is another way I could have gone. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So after battling (not really) this for months. I was finally able to work on it today.

Here's the updated version that seems to work well.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SignalBar extends CustomPainter {
  const SignalBar({this.signalStrength = 4});
  final int signalStrength;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var barBorder = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.black
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 1.5;
    var barWidth = size.width * 0.15;
    var halfWidth = size.width / 2;
    var halfHeight = size.height / 2;

// Signal bar borders
    for (var i = 0; i < signalStrength; i++) {
      canvas.drawRRect(
          RRect.fromRectAndRadius(
              Rect.fromCenter(
                  center: Offset(halfWidth * (i / 1.7), halfHeight - (i)),
                  width: barWidth,
                  height: size.height * ((i * 0.05) + 0.2)),
              const Radius.circular(8)),
          barBorder);
    }
    var barFill = Paint()
      ..color = (signalStrength <= 2)
          ? Colors.red
          : (signalStrength <= 3)
              ? Colors.orange
              : Colors.blue.shade600
      ..strokeWidth = 1;
// Signal bar fill
    for (var i = 0; i < signalStrength; i++) {
      canvas.drawRRect(
          RRect.fromRectAndRadius(
              Rect.fromCenter(
                  center: Offset(halfWidth * (i / 1.7), halfHeight - i),
                  width: barWidth,
                  height: size.height * ((i * 0.05) + 0.2)),
              const Radius.circular(8)),
          barFill);
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant SignalBar oldDelegate) {
    return oldDelegate.signalStrength != signalStrength;
  }
}
```

I suspect my previous error came from this line `size.width * (i * 0.22), size.height * -(i * 0.05)` especially the one with minus (-)

I reworked the drawing logic which resulted in the above

Here's the outcome

PS: There's a `SizedBox` at the end of the row

[image: Works]

I won't mark mine as an answer yet. Because I want to see what others can\will do.